# Problem in deriving Noise Figure for Cascaded systems

Tags: amplifier, noise, signal-to-noise

I am trying to derive Noise Figure of Cascaded System. I am making some conceptual mistake somewhere in derivation and getting wrong answer. Can any one please help me figure out where I am going wrong?

### Noise Figure of one System

Noise Figure (\$F) = \frac{(SNR)input}{(SNR)output} \$

Also,
\$F = \frac{No}{GNi}\$ 
\$No\$ = Output Noise 
\$Ni\$ = Input Noise

Where, \$No = GNi + Np\$ 
\$Np\$ = Noise produced by system itself

Thus \$F = 1 + \frac{Np}{GNi}\$

### Overall Noise Figure of two cascaded Systems

Let 2 systems be in cascade with gains & noise figure \$G_{1},G_{2}\$ & \$F_{1},F_{2} \$ respectively. 
Also following is assumed 
\$N_{1}\$ : Noise Input at system 1 
\$N_{2}\$ : Noise output at system 1 (same as noise input at system 2) 
\$N_{3}\$ : Noise output at system 2 
\$N_{p1}\$ : Noise produced by system 1 
\$N_{p2}\$ : Noise Produced by system 2 
\$G\$ : over all gain of system

Now according to my understanding 
\$G = G_{1}G_{2} \$ 
\$N2 = N_{1}G_{1} + N_{p1} \$ 
\$N3 = N_{2}G_{2} + N_{p2} \$

\$F_{1} = \frac{N_{2}}{G_{1}N_{1}} = \frac{N_{1}G_{1} + N_{p1}}{N_{1}G_{1}} = 1 + \frac{N_{p1}}{N_{1}G_{1}} \$

\$F_{1} - 1 = \frac{N_{p1}}{N_{1}G_{1}} \$ ..........1

\$(F_{1} - 1)G_{1} = \frac{N_{p1}}{N_{1}} \$

\$(F_{1} - 1)G_{1}G_{2} = \frac{N_{p1}G_{2}}{N_{1}} \$  ..........2

\$F_{2} = \frac{N_{3}}{G_{2}N_{2}} = \frac{N_{2}G_{2} + N_{p2}}{G_{2}N_{2}} = 1 + \frac{N_{p2}}{G_{2}N_{2}} \$

\$F_{2} - 1 = \frac{N_{p2}}{G_{2}N_{2}} = \frac{N_{p2}}{(N_{1}G_{1} + N_{p1})G_{2}} = \frac{N_{p2}}{N_{1}G_{1}G_{2} + N_{p1}G_{2}} = \frac{\frac{N_{p2}}{N_{1}}}{G_{1}G_{2} + \frac{N_{p1}G_{2}}{N_{1}}} \$ 
using (2) 
\$F_{2} - 1 = \frac{\frac{N_{p2}}{N_{1}}}{G_{1}G_{2} + (F_{1}-1)G_{1}G_{2}} = \frac{\frac{N_{p2}}{N_{1}}}{F_{1}G_{1}G_{2}} = \frac{N_{p2}}{F_{1}N_{1}G_{1}G_{2}} \$

\$(F_{2}-1)F_{1} = \frac{N_{p2}}{N_{1}G_{1}G_{2}} \$  ..........3

Let Overall noise figure be \$F\$, then

\$F = \frac{N_{3}}{GN_{1}} = \frac{N_{3}}{G_{1}G_{2}N_{1}} = \frac{N_{2}G_{2} + N_{p2}}{G_{1}G_{2}N_{1}} = \frac{(N_{1}G_{1} + N{p1})G_{2} + N_{p2}}{G_{1}G_{2}N_{1}} = \frac{N_{1}G_{1}G_{2} + N_{p1}G_{2} + N_{p2}}{N_{1}G_{1}G_{2}} \$ 
\$F = 1 + \frac{N_{p1}}{G_{1}N_{1}} + \frac{N_{p2}}{N_{1}G_{1}G_{2}} \$ 
\$F = 1 + (F_{1}-1) + (F_{2}-1)F_{1} \$ (using 1 & 3) 
\$F = F_{1}F_{2} \$

---

Since I know Actual formula is 
\$F = F_{1} + \frac{F_{2}-1}{G_{1}} \$ 
It means I am making mistake somewhere please Help me out.

Answer (score 1):

When you think of the noise figure of each individual block, you assume that the input noise is purely the thermal noise floor. The level of the input noise is important in the definition of the NF, otherwise you would get different numbers for NF depending on the value of the input noise, since the noise internally produced (Np) is constant.

When you start with the formula for F2, you're making:

$$
F_2=\frac{N_3}{G_2N_2}
$$

This is not correct because the noise level at the input of stage 2 is much higher than the thermal noise floor (due to the amplification G1 and the additional noise created by stage 1). For a given F2, this makes N3 much higher than it actually is, what makes the cascade NF much higher than what it's supposed to be.

You should instead use:

$$
F_2=1+\frac{N_{p2}}{G_2N_1}
$$

The important part is to understand why N1 is being used here. It's because, by the definition of each individual noise figure, we have to assume that the input noise level is the thermal noise level.

Rearranging this, we get:

$$
\frac{F_2-1}{G_1}=\frac{N_{p2}}{G_1G_2N_1}
$$

Which can be replaced in your formula:

$$
F = 1 + \frac{N_{p1}}{G_{1}N_{1}} + \frac{N_{p2}}{N_{1}G_{1}G_{2}}
$$

To get the expected result:

$$
F = F_{1} + \frac{F_{2}-1}{G_{1}}
$$

Comment: This may not be an easy concept to grasp. The way you should be thinking is that the noise figure of each individual stage is defined as if nothing else exists and if the input noise level is the minimum possible for ambient temperature, which is the thermal noise level. Think of it as the definition of noise figure for each stage.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. So what I understood is that Noise Figure kind of define relation between what noise (internally) would a system produce when input given is a particular noise level (specifically Thermal Noise N). 

But then in cascaded system input noise level to 2nd system would be higher (N1*G1 + Np1), so why would output noise of second system is still calculated using F2 (which is defined based on N1). It should be calculated using Noise Figure which is defined by noise level of N1*G1 + Np1.

Comment: I think I lack some major conceptual understating of how NF is defined, how noise is propagating via connected systems. Could you please suggest me some book where I can read about this topic.

Comment: Thanks for replying again. I got how NF is defined. But my question is now if input noise is different than thermal noise level. Then we should use some different NF (which may be related to original NF in some way) to figure out output noise instead of using NF defined on thermal noise.

Comment: "why would output noise of second system is still calculated using F2 (which is defined based on N1). It should be calculated using Noise Figure which is defined by noise level of N1*G1 + Np1" - because NF is defined for each block individually and it needs to be an intrinsic characteristic of that block, regardless of what it's connected to. The importance of the cascaded noise figure formula is that you are able to calculate the equivalent noise figure of the whole system (as if it's a black box) once we now the noise figure and gain of each particular stage.

Comment: Thanks again for replying. I understood that why we are using N1 in formula for F2. It is because we are still calculating total NF for particular noise level (i.e. N1 or say Thermal Noise Level).

Only doubt that remain is then how we will calculate noise output (for single system only) when some different noise input level is present. Will we calculate new NF for that system based on new noise level.

Comment: "if input noise is different than thermal noise level" - excellent question! In most cases, you start analyzing your receiver from the antenna feed, then the low noise amplifier, and then upstream. In these cases, you can reasonably assume that the very initial noise level is actually the thermal noise level and your noise figure calculation will be a measure of what you really care about, which is the degradation in the signal-to-noise ratio. ...

Comment: ... There are cases, though, when this is not the case. A good example I can think of is in radio telescopes where a very directional antenna is pointed to outer space with a lower temperature and the pre-amplifier is kept cold to reduce its internally produced noise. In these cases you are better off doing your calculations using noise temperature instead. If you really want to dig deep into this, the books by John D. Kraus usually provide a good analysis for these cases.

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything. I think I made mistake in assuming input noise as some kind of input power (which is generated by many reasons). But from your explaining I get sense that noise is not something which would change drastically. It is just a property of system. And we model behaviour of system fro different type of noises and not different values of noises. Since mostly noise power produced in system (specifically thermal) would be constant (i.e.based on temp.). So its kind of fixed in whole system just affected by filters (Gains & frequency).

Comment: noise and interference are two different things

Comment: Again thank you for explaining. I was in so much confusion. Thank you again.

Comment: Yeah I was treating noise as kind of some extra signal (like Interference) which would have some power and pass through various filters/system. And NF is relating output/input of that filter/system for noise power. But now I know it is different. Thank you for your valuable time. I appreciate it.

Comment: no problem and welcome to the community!