# Step by step calculation of noise factor does not match the overall system calculation

Tags: amplifier, rf, noise, signal-to-noise

I know this is a very stupid question but I've been trying for a couple of days now to figure out what mistake I'm doing.

I have two cascaded blocks as following:

Block one is an amplifier with:
Gain (G1) = 100 (or 20 dB)
Noise factor (F1) = 1.38 (NF = 1.4 dB)

Block two is the rest of receiver circuit with:
Gain (G2) = 1 (or 0 dB)
Noise factor (F2) = 10 (NF = 10 dB)

The SNR at the input of the chain is SNR_in=398 (26 dB).

If I calculate the overall SNR output step by step, it will be:

SNR at output of stage 1 = SNR_in / F1 = 398 / 1.38 = 288 (24.6 dB)

SNR at output of stage 2 (SNR_out) = 288 / 10 = 28.8 (14.6 dB)

and overall noise factor = SNR_in / SNR_out = 398 / 28.8 = 13.8 (11.4 dB)

However, using the well-known formula for the noise factor of a multi-stage cascaded network:

F = F1 + (F2-1) / G1 = 1.38 + (10-1)/100 = 1.47 (1.67 dB).

Why aren't these two numbers (13.8 and 1.47) equal?! What's the wrong thing I'm doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/467066/problem-in-deriving-noise-figure-for-cascaded-systems) that is in essence identical to this one but described in general terms. The answer provided by @joribama answers my above question as well.

In my question above, the noise added by the second stage has three components:

- The source noise amplified twice by G1 and G2 (equals 100 mW)
- The noise generated by the first amplifier and amplified by G2 (equals 38 mW)
- The noise added by the second stage, which is the original input noise (1 mW) multiplied by the G2*(F2-1). The key here is that that this additional noise is calculated from the original thermal noise, and not from the total noise at the input of the second stage. The additional noise of stage 2 becomes 1 * (10 - 1) * 1mW = 9 mW and not 1 * (10 - 1) * (100 + 38) = 1242 mW.

The reason as explained by @joribama in the other question is:

> When you think of the noise figure of each individual block, you assume that the input noise is purely the thermal noise floor. The level of the input noise is important in the definition of the NF, otherwise you would get different numbers for NF depending on the value of the input noise, since the noise internally produced (Np) is constant.